# how to merge files into one file?

Tags: file, shell

I have 3 files.

```
cat file1 
A
B
C

cat file2
2
3
4

cat file3
a
b
c
```

I need to merge them into file like this.

Output:

```
  file1  file2  file3
  A      2      a 
  B      3      b
  C      4      c
```

How can i do in shell script.

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`paste` is your friend

```
{ echo "file1\tfile2\tfile3" 
   paste file1 file2 file3 ; } > newOutFile
```

The `\t` are tab-chars, if you want a different field separator, just change that.
(If you want nicely spaced columns as the same width as the widest value in a file, then you'll need a more sophisticated solution. For that case, please post a new question).

Note that `{ ... }` is called a process group, and that the last command in a process group must be separated from the closing `}` char with a `;`.

Check out the man page for a few options.

IHTH

Comment: It there any way to write filename as title of the row (just edited my question)

Comment: @user15662 : IHTH ;-) Good luck to all.

Answer (score 1):

```
paste file1 file2 file3
```

By default, they'll be separated by tabs; you can change the delimiter with `-d` option. Use redirection to save into another file instead of printing to standard output.